# Gitlab does not generate backup files relatively to setting gitlab_rails['backup_path']

Tags: gitlab

#### Problem to solve

Im using GitLab Enterprise Edition [14.8.2-ee], I'm trying to change backup_path to my expected directory.
I changed the setting in file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

```
gitlab_rails['backup_path'] = "home/gitlab/backups"
```

Then run reconfigure, and verify configuration:

```
[root@OFFICE_GITLAB ~]# cat /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/gitlab.yml | grep -C10 'backup'
  # 4. Advanced settings
  # ==========================

  ## Repositories settings
  repositories:
    # Paths where repositories can be stored. Give the canonicalized absolute pathname.
    # NOTE: REPOS PATHS MUST NOT CONTAIN ANY SYMLINK!!!
    storages: {"default":{"path":"/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories","gitaly_address":"unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/gitaly.socket"}}

  ## Backup settings
  backup:
    path: "home/gitlab/backups"   # Relative paths are relative to Rails.root (default: tmp/backups/)
    gitaly_backup_path: "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitaly-backup" # Path of the gitaly-backup binary (default: searches $PATH)
    archive_permissions:  # Permissions for the resulting backup.tar file (default: 0600)
    keep_time:    # default: 0 (forever) (in seconds)
    pg_schema:    # default: nil, it means that all schemas will be backed up
    upload:
      # Fog storage connection settings, see http://fog.io/storage/ .
      connection: 
      # The remote 'directory' to store your backups. For S3, this would be the bucket name.
      remote_directory: 
      multipart_chunk_size: 
      encryption: 
      encryption_key: 
      storage_options: {}
      storage_class: 

  ## Pseudonymizer settings
  pseudonymizer:
    manifest:
```

Then run command:

```
gitlab-backup create BACKUP=$(date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S)
```

There is error:

```
[root@OFFICE_GITLAB crons]# sudo gitlab-backup create BACKUP=$(date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S)
2024-03-11 17:46:22 +0800 -- Dumping database ... 
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/home
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/database.rb:28:in `dump'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:71:in `run_create_task'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:36:in `block in create'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:35:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:35:in `create'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It seems that the Backup task is trying to create directories as same as the setting gitlab_rails['backup_path'], but in the /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/ directory.
Then I run this:

```
mkdir -p /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/home/gitlab/backups
chmod -R 777 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/home/gitlab/backups
```

Then I run again the backup command, and it can generates backup but all data is located in this directory /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/home/gitlab/backups, not the expected directory /home/gitlab/backups:

```
sudo gitlab-backup create BACKUP=$(date +%d%m%Y%H%M%S)
2024-03-11 17:58:26 +0800 -- Dumping database ... 
Dumping PostgreSQL database gitlabhq_production ... [DONE]
2024-03-11 17:58:44 +0800 -- done
2024-03-11 17:58:44 +0800 -- Dumping repositories ... 

....

[root@OFFICE_GITLAB backups]# cd /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/home/gitlab/backups
[root@OFFICE_GITLAB backups]# du -sh ./*
99M     ./db
8.0G    ./repositories
```

So Gitlab is generating backup data to /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/home/gitlab/backups instead of /home/gitlab/backups .
Please help me, how to fix this ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the issue that you are using `home/gitlab/backups` as opposed to `/home/gitlab/backups`? Maybe specifying the root directory will make a difference.

Otherwise I would imagine that there is something else wrong with your config as creating backups on my instance with the aforementioned path seems to work.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's my misconfiguration. I updated to /home/gitlab/backups and it works